# mirror not working

Tags: mirror

[image]

it looks like there's a copy of the cube that isnt being affected by the mirror.

when i was building this model:

[image]

i set up the modifier to the default cube and went on my way. but now, it isnt working.

Comment: Can you post the file? Or more information? I don't see how the first and second image correlate.

Comment: theres no file that needs to be posted. when i set up the mirror modifier to the default cube, it doesn't work. the second image is just to demonstrate that it was working before, and i could create a model with symmetry. i am not doing anything different to the default cube, than i was when i made that model.

Comment: "It doesn't work"? In what way? I asked for the model because I don't have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: in the top image you can see i have pulled a vertice inward. but some copy of the cube seems to be present, and the edge of the cube remains the same. i do not know why this copy exists.

Comment: IMO it is best practice to halve the model and work from one side. As answered below. The "copy" is the left mirroring over right and the right mirroring over left.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have a complete cube with a mirror modifier attached to it. This modifier doesn't copy changes of one side to the other, it duplicates one side and creates it on the other (in real time), where there should be empty space if the modifier is disabled.

Delete the half of the cube you aren't working on.

Comment: couldnt be this. i definitely did not delete any half of the cube the first time. from the moment the program loaded, i went modifier>mirror>edit mode> and started building the model. i didn't delete anything from the cube.

Comment: You could try it...

Comment: unfortunately, its not working anyway. half the cube gets deleted and thats all that happens. this is very strange. thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the result? Or the file?

Comment: i think i found a bug. the only big thing in blender that i have changed today in the time since making that model, is enabling "loop tools" in user preferences. i have now disabled it, and the mirror modifier is working as intended.

Answer (score -1):

having "loop tools" enabled seems to mess with something in blender, and the mirror modifier does not work the way it should. disabling loop tools fixes my problem.

the version of blender is 2.78